# vkCmdDispatchIndirect with non-zero base offsets?

Tags: vulkan

I'm using vkCmdDispatchIndirect, but I'd like to be able to specify non-zero base values, as you can with vkCmdDispatchBase. However, the struct VkDispatchIndirectCommand only has members for the number of workgroups, not base values.

The obvious answer is that you can't, but it seems odd to me that they'd provide the non-zero base functionality only in the non-indirect case, I figure I must be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Thanks for free 15 points :D

`vkCmdDispatchBase` was part of Device Groups extension, so the command was possibly only an afterthought.

If you think Indirect version should be in the API, the community here cannot help you. You need to petition Khronos at [KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/issues).